# How to solve "Internal package processing error" at Window Phone App Submission Process?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When i make new submission for update my current Window Phone App to WindowsDevCenter>> Submissions >> Packages and after finish uploading that errors always appear

> "Internal package processing error: System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) at
>   Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Utilities.UnpublishedPhoneProductGuidProvider.GetIdByPackageFamilyName(String
>   name) in
>   c:\B\16\DCEProductCatalog_HFJuneLast\S\private\DCEProductCatalog\src\ProductCatalogFD\Utilities\UnpublishedPhoneProductGuidProvider.cs:line
>   208 at
>   Microsoft.MarketplaceServices.Ingestion.ProductCatalogService.Controllers.V1.PackageValidationV1Controller."

I had valid Windows Dev Account and my previous app was on window phone store. My new update app working surely at Window Phone Emulator and Real Window Phone Device but that "Internal package processing error" always happen in submission case. Please explain how can i solve that problem?

Currently i using Visual Studio 2010, Window Phone SDK 7.1 and my app target for Window Phone 7.1 and 8.

Comment: Contact the store about this error, as the callstack indicates it's in their code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, take a look at this thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/81fcb869-6e0e-4540-b72b-f9398b103d64/wpslcryptic-error-seen-while-trying-to-upgrade-wp8-app?forum=wpdevelop

I think MS will solve this soon...i hope!

Comment: Thank i waiting for microsoft fix. :)